# Unable to change screen brightness [NVIDIA GPU] [Ubuntu 20.04]

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, gpu

OS     : Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64 
Kernel : 5.8.0-63-generic 
GPU    : Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 
Driver : 470.57.02 
System : Lenovo Legion 5 15ARH05 
CPU    : AMD Ryzen 5 4600H with Radeon Graphics

Changing brightness using slider or hotkeys does nothing the brightness is always at 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to NVIDIA Driver Version: 510.47.03 fixed the issue.